# Why do I get "The underlying connection was closed." when I try to enter form credentials for a crawl rule?

Tags: crawling, crawl-rules, crawl-external-content

When I'm setting up a crawl rule, I check 'Specify form credentials', wait a minute and then get an error message:

> An unexpected error was encountered while trying to connect to *https://site.org/login*. The error is "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.". The site might be unavailable or it could not be reached within the specified timeout or the proxy settings are not configured. To increase the timeout value or to configure the proxy settings, use the Proxy and timeouts page.

I don't seem to be able to set it for any site.

Logged into the server, I can get to the form.  What's going on?

Comment: I've noticed that http forms are fine, it's only https forms that cause an error.  That is, http://facebook.com brings up the normal login form, https://facebook.com causes an error.

Comment: Hmmm, I applied SP1 and now the form credentials window comes up, I get an NTLM invitation to log in and then nothing.

Comment: Dan, did you ever figure out this issue? I seem to be having the same problem. http forms work fine, but https forms give me this error: "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel." I have also disabled lookback check and added the site's certificate under "Manage Trust" in Central Admin.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that SharePoint 2010 cannot access web services running SSL unless the root certificate of the web service is trusted in SharePoint.

Try create a new trust relationship for the root certificate under CA - Security - Manage Trust - New.

Comment: It turns out that the root cert for the certificate provider for my target site is already installed, because we're using the same cert provider.  No luck though, just a blank dialog box when I try to enter credentials.

Comment: Yes but have you added the root certificate under CA - Security - Manage Trust. It is not enough that the Root Certificate is installed on the server! The problem is that SharePoint does not trust the certificate even though it is trusted of the Windows server! Try export the root certificate from the Certificate MMC and add it to a new trust i Central Administration

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint Stack Exchange! Please don't add your name as a signature to posts as this doesn't provide valuable information. Your user name is already displayed on the post.

Comment: Yep, it's in Central Admin.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. At first I didn't think Rasmus' solution worked for me, but then I realized that SharePoint requires all of the certificates in the certificate chain to be listed. In our case, I had a self-signed certificate through Go Daddy. Originally I had only added the bottom level certificate in SharePoint, and that didn't work. But after I included two Go Daddy Certification Authority certificates in Central Admin, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

did you disable to lookback check for that server?
Common mistake.

Comment: Yes, disabled long ago.